# Get list of weeks that start on a Friday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I want to count the number of the weeks, starting from Friday.

For more explanation: usually the counting starts on Sunday or Monday, but in this case, I want to make it start on Friday.

Some examples:

```
2nd Jan 2015 (Fri) ~ 8th Jan 2015 (Thu) : 1st week of 2015
...
25th Dec 2015 (Fri) ~ 31st Dec 2015 (Thu) : 52nd week of 2015
1st Jan 2016 (Fri) ~ 7th Jan 2016 (Thu)   : 1st week of 2016

...

30th Dec 2016 (Fri) ~ 5th Jan 2017 (Thu) : 53rd week of 2016
6th Jan 2017 (Fri) ~ 12th Jan 2017 (Thu) : 1st week of 2017
```

What I need to do is

1) to get the week number from the date

ex.

```
input: Fri, 02 Jan 2015
output: 1

input: Sun, 27 Dec 2015
output: 52
```

2) to get the date range for the given week number.

I found that `.strftime("%V")` does almost this, but it counts weeks by every Monday.

Does anyone know nice solution to this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. For example, "I want to get the week numbers for weeks that start on a Friday." makes no sense because no week starts on a Friday. You need to clarify your question. Please edit the question rather than try to explain in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
my_array = Array.new
(Date.today..Date.today.next_year).each do |date|
    if date.wday == 5
        end_week = date + 6.days
        my_array << "#{date.day.ordinalize} #{date.strftime('%b')} #{date.strftime('%Y')} (#{date.strftime('%a')}) ~ #{end_week.day.ordinalize} #{end_week.strftime('%b')} #{end_week.strftime('%Y')} (#{end_week.strftime('%a')}) : #{date.strftime('%U')} week of #{date.strftime('%Y')}"
    end
end
# sample output of first element of array
# 30th Oct 2015 (Fri) ~ 5th Nov 2015 (Thu) : 43 week of 2015
```

**Note:** You can set any range. here I have set from `Today` to `next year`

> %U - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday
>   as the first day of the first week (00..53)
>
> %W - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday
>   as the firstday of the first week (00..53)

for more info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need.
However, there is one problem:


       "25th Dec 2015 (Fri) ~ 31st Dec 2015 (Thu) : 51 week of 2015",
       "1st Jan 2016 (Fri) ~ 7th Jan 2016 (Thu) : 00 week of 2016"

       "30th Dec 2016 (Fri) ~ 5th Jan 2017 (Thu) : 52 week of 2016",
       "6th Jan 2017 (Fri) ~ 12th Jan 2017 (Thu) : 01 week of 2017"

Here, on the second one, it starts with first week, not zero week.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the variety of operation on the dates here...

[DateAndTime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_week)

In your case, the below will work for you.

all_week(start_day = Date.beginning_of_week)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but how can I get the week number from that? I couldn't find the one that change beginning_of_week when calculating weeknumber.

Comment: This is not an answer. It would not even be a useful comment.